# Input string was ERROR

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have SQL table with `bigint` Telephone  `field` as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE Userinfo(UserName varchar(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,Telephone bigint,Mobile bigint,);
```

and
aspx.vb file sql insert statement like this

```
Dim stel As Int64 = Int64.Parse(tel.Text)
```

here I got an error 
I also tried

```
 Dim stel As Int = Int.Parse(tel.Text)
 Dim stel As string= string.Parse(tel.Text)
 Dim stel As Int32 = Int32.Parse(tel.Text)
```

Comment: is that comma at end of Create Statement needed ?

Comment: no this is due to next field also there which i deleted this one remain

Comment: my problem is that i want  equivalent of bigint in vb.net

Comment: Check what value comes in the `tel.Text` and make sure there are no non numeric values in that string

Comment: Why do you need Telephone to be bigint? I would suggest to keep it as  VARCAHR since we rarely perform any arithmatic operation on Telephone numbers like Average, Addtion, Subtraction etc.

Comment: I just wanna check out why this error arising yes i can do this with VARCAHR  but why not with bigint http://stackoverflow.com/users/3676368/swapnil

Comment: Depending on where you live the phone number might have leading zeros which will not be stored in any integer datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining it as `Long`. Please Give a try of

```
dim stel as long
stel=CType(tel.text, Long)
```

and please do recheck that the `tel.text` should not contain values other than numerics.

**Note:**

this too is equivalent to using Int64.if same exception is arised ,check for other possible causes for it.to know about various sql datatypes and their .net framework equivalents please go to [SQL datatypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)